# How to repeat part of code multiple times in html + php + bootstrap. script not working

Tags: html, loops, while-loop

My code retrieves information from database and displayes it. I am using bootstrap and i am very new to this website coding. I used java script but the code which displays the content just doesn't show up.

I want to repeat the code which is in script tag in second code so that it can display all the books available in the database. Probably a while loop will do?

Here my code with and without script with output

[image: without script]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Timeline </title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/local.css" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>   

      <style>

        div {
            padding-bottom:20px;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="wrapper">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">V-cart</a>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav side-nav">
                    <li><a href="timeline.php"><i class="fa fa-font"></i> Timeline</a></li>          
                    <li><a href="request.php"><i class="fa fa-font"></i> Request Ad</a></li>
                    <li><a href="post.php"><i class="fa fa-font"></i> Post Ad</a></li>

                </ul>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right navbar-user">
                    <li class="dropdown messages-dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> Messages <span class="badge"></span> <b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li class="dropdown-header">No Messages</li>
                            <li class="message-preview">
                                <a href="#">
                                    <span class="avatar"><i class="fa fa-bell"></i></span>
                                    <span class="message">Security alert</span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li class="message-preview">
                                <a href="#">
                                    <span class="avatar"><i class="fa fa-bell"></i></span>
                                    <span class="message">Security alert</span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Go to Inbox <span class="badge"></span></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown user-dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> User Name<b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="profileme.php"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> Profile</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-gear"></i> Settings</a></li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="index.php"><i class="fa fa-power-off"></i> Log Out</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>

         <hr />
        <div class="container">
            <div class="page-header">
                <h1 id="timeline">User Events</h1>
            </div>



<?php




define('DB_NAME', 'userdb');
define('DB_USER', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
define('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1');

$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

$db_selected = mysql_select_db("userdb");

if (!$db_selected) {
    die('Can\'t use ' . DB_NAME . ': ' . mysql_error());
}


$sql = "SELECT * FROM postad";
$myData = mysql_query($sql,$link);
$count= mysql_num_rows($myData);


$record= mysql_fetch_array($myData);
# $record = mysql_fetch_assoc($myData);



mysql_close();
?>











            <ul class="timeline">





                <li>
                    <div class="timeline-badge info"><i class="fa fa-unlock"></i></div>
                    <div class="timeline-panel">
                        <div class="timeline-heading">
                            <h4 class="timeline-title"><?php echo $record['title'];  ?></h4>                            
                            <span><i class="fa fa-clock-o fa-2x"></i></span>
                            <hr />
                        </div>
                        <div class="timeline-body">
Author : <?php echo $record['author'];  ?> <br>
Semester : <?php echo $record['semester'];  ?> <br>
Details: <?php echo $record['description'];  ?> <br>




                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>



              <!--  <li class="timeline-inverted">
                    <div class="timeline-badge success"><i class="fa fa-unlock"></i></div>
                    <div class="timeline-panel">
                        <div class="timeline-heading">
                            <h4 class="timeline-title">Book 2</h4>
                            <span><i class="fa fa-clock-o fa-2x"></i> 57 minutes ago</span>
                            <hr />
                        </div>
                        <div class="timeline-body">
                             <p>Details</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li> -->

            </ul>



        </div> 
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

[image: With script]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Timeline </title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/local.css" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>   

      <style>

        div {
            padding-bottom:20px;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="wrapper">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">V-cart</a>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav side-nav">
                    <li><a href="timeline.php"><i class="fa fa-font"></i> Timeline</a></li>          
                    <li><a href="request.php"><i class="fa fa-font"></i> Request Ad</a></li>
                    <li><a href="post.php"><i class="fa fa-font"></i> Post Ad</a></li>

                </ul>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right navbar-user">
                    <li class="dropdown messages-dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> Messages <span class="badge"></span> <b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li class="dropdown-header">No Messages</li>
                            <li class="message-preview">
                                <a href="#">
                                    <span class="avatar"><i class="fa fa-bell"></i></span>
                                    <span class="message">Security alert</span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li class="message-preview">
                                <a href="#">
                                    <span class="avatar"><i class="fa fa-bell"></i></span>
                                    <span class="message">Security alert</span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Go to Inbox <span class="badge"></span></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown user-dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> User Name<b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="profileme.php"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> Profile</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-gear"></i> Settings</a></li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="index.php"><i class="fa fa-power-off"></i> Log Out</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>

         <hr />
        <div class="container">
            <div class="page-header">
                <h1 id="timeline">User Events</h1>
            </div>



<?php




define('DB_NAME', 'userdb');
define('DB_USER', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
define('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1');

$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

$db_selected = mysql_select_db("userdb");

if (!$db_selected) {
    die('Can\'t use ' . DB_NAME . ': ' . mysql_error());
}


$sql = "SELECT * FROM postad";
$myData = mysql_query($sql,$link);
$count= mysql_num_rows($myData);


$record= mysql_fetch_array($myData);
# $record = mysql_fetch_assoc($myData);



mysql_close();
?>








            <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min".js>


            <ul class="timeline">





                <li>
                    <div class="timeline-badge info"><i class="fa fa-unlock"></i></div>
                    <div class="timeline-panel">
                        <div class="timeline-heading">
                            <h4 class="timeline-title"><?php echo $record['title'];  ?></h4>                            
                            <span><i class="fa fa-clock-o fa-2x"></i></span>
                            <hr />
                        </div>
                        <div class="timeline-body">
Author : <?php echo $record['author'];  ?> <br>
Semester : <?php echo $record['semester'];  ?> <br>
Details: <?php echo $record['description'];  ?> <br>




                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>

                </script>

              <!--  <li class="timeline-inverted">
                    <div class="timeline-badge success"><i class="fa fa-unlock"></i></div>
                    <div class="timeline-panel">
                        <div class="timeline-heading">
                            <h4 class="timeline-title">Book 2</h4>
                            <span><i class="fa fa-clock-o fa-2x"></i> 57 minutes ago</span>
                            <hr />
                        </div>
                        <div class="timeline-body">
                             <p>Details</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li> -->

            </ul>



        </div> 
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: My reputation is low so cant post more than 2 links, also stackoverflow is not able to detect my code coorectly that's why i had to put code in pastebin

Comment: Welcome to SO, please visit the [help] to see how to ask a question here. One hint, use the snippet editor if you have executable code, shift right 4 spaces if not

Comment: Even for a single reputation, you can post the relevant codes.

Comment: Closing as OffTopic: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: **Do not use `mysql_*` functions. They are deprecated.**